# How to make custom "button" like Facebook for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make my home screen for my android application like Facebook for Android. Is there anyone know how to make this layout? I am still newbie for Android Development.

[image: Facebook for Android]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three linear layout with horizontal orientation and make their parent layout with vertical orientation, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:baselineAligned="false" android:orientation="horizontal">
  <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1">
      <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout>   
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout>   
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
            <ImageView android:background="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="caption"/>
        </LinearLayout>   
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I have found the other solution that use GridView from Android.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a 3x3 table, put 3 buttons per row, and a background image as the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon1"></Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon2"></Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon3"></Button>

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon4"></Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon5"></Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon6"></Button>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon7"></Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon8"></Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon9"></Button>
</TableRow>
```

Change the @drawable/iconX to whatever background image you want/need.

Comment: Definitely a table layout would be a better approach instead of several nested linearlayouts!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:
**home_icon_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:focusable="true" android:layout_width="90.0dip" android:layout_height="70.0dip" android:layout_margin="5.0dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="center" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="@color/home_text_color" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And **home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/home_icons" android:paddingTop="5.0dip" android:paddingBottom="24.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="bottom|center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:id="@id/home_news_feed_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
        <include android:id="@id/home_profile_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
        <include android:id="@id/home_friends_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="bottom|center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:id="@id/home_messages_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
        <include android:id="@id/home_places_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
        <include android:id="@id/home_groups_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="bottom|center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include android:id="@id/home_events_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
        <include android:id="@id/home_photos_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
        <include android:id="@id/home_chat_icon" layout="@layout/home_icon_view" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```